# Starting service from another service

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to start a service from another service. But wonder what's going wrong. The code is like

```
class Service1 extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Service2.class);
        startService(service);
    }
}
```

And Service2 is

```
class Service2 extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the Toast "Hello" in Service1 but not getting Toast "Service Started" from Service2

Comment: Try `Service1.this` or `getBaseContext()` instead of `getApplicationContext()` in intent to start Service1

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I've tried many possibilities including this but nothing has worked

Comment: No... I'm not getting any error. Just nothing is happening..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using `getApplicationContext()` you should use `Service1.this` or `getBaseContext()` . Have you declared your Service2 in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: Ohhhh.... The Manifest... I should slap myself a hunderd times for this... Anyways, thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries! I think we all know these situations only too well ;)

Comment: Manifest for sure always gets ya, but seriously I have also had problems with getApplicationContext() when dealing with Services? It's strange to me because it seems so natural to think Application Context when inside a Service but yea I always go with getBaseContext() if dealing with Services or even BroadcastReceivers